# A Docker image disappears after building it

Tags: image, docker, build, ls

A Docker image disappears after building it. Why does it?

I'm working on CentOS and following "Build the app" of the official guide of Docker https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/.

I ran `docker build --tag=friendlyhello .` and got

```
Successfully built bca038cfb384
Successfully tagged friendlyhello:latest
```

I confirmed that the image was registered locally.

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY                                                        TAG                   IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
friendlyhello                                                     latest                bca038cfb384        About a minute ago   153MB
python                                                            3.7.2-slim            bc5085cee55b        6 days ago           143MB
```

However, then after a few minutes later, the images built disappeared.
After tagging an image, the new image created also vanishes.

Why did they, and how can I solve it?

Comment: maybe a cronjob ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein Not seems so. I searched for cron jobs `crontab -l` for `root` and other users, but it showed `no crontab for USER`. Also, `/etc/cron.*/` have no files recently made.

Comment: @MostafaHussein Nothing "maybe" about it. It was for me. I had to edit a docker-cleanup script that was deleting all but a certain list of images every hour. Needless to say, the new image wasn't on the list. Thank you for the pointer.